Dependency issues
https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/issues/612#issuecomment-2241719708
error: failed to select a version for `subtle`.
    ... required by package `rustls v0.22.2`
    ... which satisfies dependency `rustls = "^0.22.2"` of package `reqwest v0.12.4`
    ... which satisfies dependency `reqwest = "^0.12"` (locked to 0.12.4) of package `tauri v2.0.0-beta.23`
    ... which satisfies dependency `tauri = "^2.0.0-beta"` (locked to 2.0.0-beta.23) of package `blockmesh_tauri v0.0.108 (/Users/ohaddahan/RustroverProjects/block-mesh-monorepo/libs/blockmesh-bin/src-tauri)`
versions that meet the requirements `^2.5.0` are: 2.6.1, 2.5.0

all possible versions conflict with previously selected packages.

  previously selected package `subtle v2.4.1`
    ... which satisfies dependency `subtle = "^2.4"` (locked to 2.4.1) of package `digest v0.10.7`
    ... which satisfies dependency `digest = "^0.10.7"` (locked to 0.10.7) of package `solana-sdk v1.18.19`
    ... which satisfies dependency `solana-sdk = "^1.18.2"` (locked to 1.18.19) of package `blockmesh_tauri v0.0.108 (/Users/ohaddahan/RustroverProjects/block-mesh-monorepo/libs/blockmesh-bin/src-tauri)`

